# Simple change in velocity question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

> The hand of a clock is 1cm long. find the change in velocity of the hand in 15 seconds.

The question is pretty simple, $v=2\pi R/T$ and then using the vector addition one can easily get answer which is $\pi \sqrt{2}/30$

But as we also know that $\vec{ \Delta V}$=$\vec{\Delta R}\over \Delta T$ So why can't I do this question this way.

[image]/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is wrong. The correct formula is:
$$\bar {\vec v}=\large{\frac{\Delta \vec r}{\Delta t}}$$

$\bar {\vec v}$ is the average velocity.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks for the change in the velocity vector, which should be done by vector subtraction, not addition. This would give you pi*sqrt2/30, as you have, but directed at an angle of 225 deg - toward the center of the circle, as it should be. (The first vector is +i, the second is -j, so the subtraction is -j-i, which gives the correct angle.)

Your second formula is the avg velocity of the tip of the clock hand in going from point 1 to point 2. That is not what the problem is asking.